# Using function from user control (razor syntax)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor, user-controls

Hey guys I am stuck for a week for trying acces a function made in user control.
I use razor syntax (webmatrix)

I have 2 ascx files

**hoop.ascx:**

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" ClassName="basic" %>  

<script runat="server">

    Function Random(from, to)
            Randomize
            Random = 1 + INT(RND(from)*to)
        End Function
</script>
```

**webform.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" aspcompat=true %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wikibooks" TagName="basic" Src="hoop.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="connectie" TagName="con" Src="connectie.ascx" %>

<html>
<head>
<title>Testing it</title>
</head>
<body>

<wikibooks:basic runat="server"/>
<connectie:con runat="server" />

<%
   Response.Write(Random(1, 1000))
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me with this problem (how I can handle it )

when i do this i get the error:

```
[BC30108] 'random' is a type and cannot be used as an expression
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while for me so, improve as needed:

1. Strongly suggest you rename your own `Functions` - use names other than built-in names (.Net). So in your **hoop.ascx** `UserControl`:

   ```
   Public Shared Function RandomGen(fromValue As Integer, toValue As Integer)

      'Random is a built-in class in .net
       Dim rnd As New Random()
       RandomGen = rnd.Next(fromValue, toValue)

   End Function
   ```
2. Your **hoop.ascx** `UserControl` `ClassName` is `basic` as declared:

   `<%@ Control Language="VB" ClassName="basic" %>`

   So to call your (`Shared`) function from it *in* **webform.aspx**:

   `<%=basic.RandomGen(100, 200)%>`

BTW, this isn't `razor` syntax - this is `WebForms` syntax. Razor would be `vbhtml` or `cshtml` (for c#).

Hth...

Comment: I have a dim like dim test = "hey" and when i call it like <%=basic.test%> i get an error. is there a way to call dims  ?

Comment: @Mralwayswrong `Public Shared Test As String = "foo"`

Comment: Hey @EdSF I have an function that has some database in it but i get the error : Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class

do u know how i can fix this problem

Comment: Hey @EdSF what if I have a function with database (similar to Mr Always wrong structure) but keep getting errors is it possible to use database in functions in user control ?

Comment: @profa Without details, I'd say of course you can call functions that do data work - just like in any flavor of ASP.Net (web forms, web pages, mvc/web api). I suggest you ask a _new_ question with specifics (instead of commenting).